# How to incrementally load previous items of listview

Tags: c#, listview

When my application get started through the commandline it gets passed a parameter that contains the document that should be opened and a number which represents the page where the document ist opened. Let's say i start at Page 15 and the user wants to see items 14-1 which weren't loaded since i started at 15. Currently im loading those in with the rest and inserting them at the top but if I do I'll lose the page position at which the application started. I've tried listviews **scrollintoview** method yet that doesn't work as my listview only gets populated after the execution of **GetPagedItemsAsync**.
My question is: **is there another way to retain the position of my item? Or is it best to insert them after my listview was populated perhaps with the scrolloffset?**
Loading the pages normally and then scroll to the item probably won't work as the item may not have been realized yet.

To kinda visualize what i mean:

```
Item1 (page that is in the document but wasn't loaded)*

Item2 (page i started with)

Item3

Item4
```

I'll gladly edit my quesiton if anything is unclear.

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand what you're asking, but it seems like you know how many items there will be when fully loaded. How about inserting dummies into your list that you replace when the proper items are loaded?

Comment: I know how many pages get fetched each time and i know when everything is loaded (when pagecount reached its maximum). But i don't quite understand what you mean with dummies?

Comment: If you create placeholders for all your items `ScrollIntoView` should work. A simple example;
    `list.Add("page 1 <-- dummy data, will be replaced");`

    `list.Add("page 2 <-- dummy data, will be replaced");`

    `list.Add("page 3 <-- real data");`

Comment: The problem is that i can't load all items straight away since the document can contain many pages exhausting  memory. Or did i misunderstood you?

Comment: Well my suggestion was to load data lazy on demand and use dummies in the list so that the number of items in the list are the same but the actual data is replaced. Might be that I misunderstand you. Maybe you should add some code that shows what you tried so far and someone will surely suggest a good solution :)